# Ruby getting value from key value pair gives key and value in one string

Tags: ruby, sequel

My hash looks like:

```
{:system=>"rr1k1"}
```

If I do:

```
puts @var[:system]
```

It looks like:

```
systemrr1k1
```

How do I just get rr1k1 without doing a @var.each ?

EDIT:

In response to comments below.  My actual variable is set from a db query with sequel that only has one result.  When I just do a puts on the variable, it looks like:

```
puts @var
#<Sequel::MySQL::Dataset: "select distinct lower(system) as system from client where db = 'CLIENTDB1'">
```

And if I do a loop on it, I get:

```
@var.each do |x|
    p x
end
```

Gives me:

```
{:system=>"rr1k1"}
```

but puts @var[:system] gives me

```
systemrr1k1
```

Comment: It works as expected if you have `@var = {:system=>"rr1k1"}`

Comment: I think you have a problem. `@var = {:sys­tem=>"rr1k1"}; puts @var[­:system]` will give "rr1k1". Can you provide your script in one block?

Comment: What do you get if you `p @var` rather than `puts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `Sequel::MySQL::Dataset` in `@var`, you can see that from the `puts @var` output. `Sequel::MySQL::Dataset` gets its `[]` method from `Sequel::Dateset` and [that method](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sequel/Sequel/Dataset#%5B%5D-instance_method):

> **- (Object) `[`](*conditions)**
>
> Returns the first record matching the conditions. Examples:
>
> ```
> DB[:table][:id=>1] # SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id = 1) LIMIT 1
> # => {:id=1}
> ```

That means that `@var[:system]` will give you a *row*, not a single value.

Perhaps you really want:

```
puts @var.first[:system]
```

to peel off the first (and only) row in the result set and then pull the `:system` value out of that single row.

Comment: I had tried .first, but had it in wrong order. I did @var[:system].first

Answer (score 0):

Your `@var` is a [Sequel Dataset](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html), which is an [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html). To access your data you'll have to reference the row or use `.first` like so:

```
puts @var[0][:system] # "rr1k1"

puts @var.first[:system]  # "rr1k1"
```

Since it is a Dataset there may be other rows so if you want to properly loop over every result you'll have to use `.each`.